# Validação de usuário e senha em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou fazendo um jogo que necessita de autenticação para jogar. Como faço para validar usuário e senha salvos em um arquivo *.txt*?

O código que eu já desenvolvi até então é esse:

```
void login(){
int escolhe_dificuldade(); // função para selecionar dificuldade do jogo

FILE *pont_arq;
     pont_arq = fopen("arquivo_palavra.txt", "r");// arquivo onde esta armazenado nome,senha de acesso por linhas.
     if(pont_arq == NULL) {
     printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
     return 1;
}
```

---

```
char usuario[20]; 
char senha[20],string2[100],string3[100];



printf(" Digite o usuario: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario);
    printf(" Digite a senha: ");
    scanf("%s", senha);
     printf("\n");
     printf("\n");

     while( (fscanf(pont_arq, "%s %s", &string2, &string3)) != EOF ) {

        //strcpy(string2, usuario);
        //strcpy(string3, senha);

        if ( (strcmp("%s" == string2 && "%s" == string3)) ) {

            printf("\nBem-Vindo!\n");
            playCPU(escolhe_dificuldade());
        } else {

            printf("\nSeu login ou senha estão errados!");

        }

    }


    fclose(pont_arq);    


  }
```

Comment: Estude  a sintaxe da função strcmp, por exemplo em:     http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcmp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro passo para não haver falhas na sua autenticação é definir como vai ser o seu arquivo onde vai ser armazenado o login e senha. Uma linha o usuário e a próxima a senha?

scanf correto:

```
scanf("%s", &usuario);
scanf("%s", &senha);
```

Tente esse código:

```
if ( ( strcmp( string2, usuario) == 0) &&
     ( strcmp( string3, senha ) == 0 ))
{
    // OK
...
}
```